# Edit default error messages MySQL

Tags: mysql, unix, config

At work we use two MySQL databases that have a slave-master relationship. Accidentally inserting/updating/deleting in the wrong place leads to at least half an hour fixing the databases. To avoid this, we are revising the grants for users.
However, to point the user in the correct direction, we also like to change the default error message that is thrown by MySQL.

On OSx, there is a file called `errmsg-utf8.txt` in `/usr/local/mysql/share/`. However, editing this file does not result in a changed error message. Obviously, the MySQL service has been restarted after the change.

Is there a way to change the default error message?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you can hack it using a different/custom locale/language (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-message-language.html)

Comment: It is obviously about "restarting the service" after editing that file. You need to __recompile__ your distribution after such changes. [More](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/error-message-adding.html) and [even more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html) and [even much more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/)

Comment: Oops, missed that. Thanks